# Open pdf/doc/xls in other iphone app with modification acknowledgment

Tags: iphone, ipad, document, file-sharing, uidocumentinteraction

I know how to implement inter-app communication. I did it with some examples.

Now I need to send/share a doc/xls file with other application in my iPad/iPhone that have url schemes to open in such files.

Questions

1. How Can I find the list of application that has url schemes to open such files.
2. How can I limit the open-in in some specified application with in the above list.

Important

1. How can I prevent the shared document from further sharing (such as email/print).
2. And if the shared file is modified by that application how can I know it.
3. How can I get back the shared file after modification.
4. While sharing is there is any option to make it as read-only,read-write privilege.

Answer (score 0):

- In general, it is impossible to prevent a document from being shared.  You can only make it more frustrating.
- Everything else depends on the URL scheme you are using.  For example, if it is the `file://` scheme then access is controlled by the OS and filesystem.  If it is the `http://` scheme then access is controlled by the HTTP server, etc.

Comment: Hi Dietrich thanks, But I am thinking in case of inter-app communication using openURL:

Comment: That is what I am talking about.  Just because an API uses URLs does not make it any easier to prevent it from being shared.  And the access control / modification notifications are all done through the URL's protocol.

Comment: Dietrich, I saw some apps can define url scheme that can accept files(pdf, doc) How can I do this?. with such privillages any idea? see this : http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes

Comment: If you create a URL scheme for your app it is so other applications can control your app, not the other way around.